# Move UIView from ViewController to Window

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, window

Basically, I have a `UIView` in my `UIViewController`. I want a user to be able to press a button and then the `UIView` moves from my `UIViewController` to the my application's window so that the `UIView` will be above all `UIViewControllers`. The only thing I could think of doing was

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
    var view = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(view)
    }

    func tappedAction() {
         window.bringSubview(toFront: view)
    }
}
```

but that didn't work. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just bring the subview that's in your `UIViewController` to the front of your `UIWindow`.

You need to:

1. Remove the `UIView` from the `UIViewController`.
2. Add the `UIView` to the main `UIWindow`.

I chose to do this in this way:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var customView: UIView!

    // Load the main view of the UIViewController.
    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Load the custom view that we will be transferring.
        self.customView = UIView(frame: .init(x: 100, y: 250, width: 250, height: 250))
        self.customView.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(customView)
        // Transfer the view. Call this method in your trigger function.
        transfer(self.customView)
    }

    func transfer(_ view: UIView) {
        // Remove the view from the UIViewController.
        view.removeFromSuperview()
        // Add the view to the UIWindow.
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.addSubview(view)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set frame fro view at  `var view = UIView()`

then you should add to window   `window.addSubview(view)`

Answer (score 0):

If your view is added on window then `window.bringSubview(toFront: view)` will work otherwise it will not.

If your view is added on window then you can use `bringSubview(toFront:)` like that:
Example:

```
        let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
        let view1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: window.frame.origin.x, y: window.frame.origin.y, width: window.frame.width, height: window.frame.height))
        window.addSubview(view1);
        view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        let view2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 50))
        view2.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        window.addSubview(view2)
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.bringSubview(toFront: view1)
```

**So you need to add your view in window:**

```
    window.addSubview(view)
```

Comment: I want my view to originally be on my UIViewController and then if a user taps a button with the function tappedAction(), then the view goes from my UIViewController to the key window. See my updated code in my question

Comment: bringSubview will work on only child view not the other. So if you want to show the view on the window then the view must be in the hierarchy of window

Comment: You need to remove from parent view and add it on window when user tap on button